# Upload image to Google Photos and mark it as a Photosphere

Tags: google-photos

How do I tell Google Photos that an image is 360?

I have a space scene made in Blender & Cycles, and I have rendered it as a 360 (equirectangular) image, and it worked. But when I try to upload it to Google Photos it doesn't know it's a Photosphere.

Is it some value stored in the image file? Can I tell Google Photos to view it as a Photosphere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about uploading files to Google Photos. The fact that those files have been rendered in Blender is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Maybe it is an EXIF label that tells Google it is a photosphere? I don't know. Try inspecting one with a tag editor like ExifTool and see if you can find the tag responsible for that and can recreate it in your render.

Comment: I was not quite sure where to post this. Where would be most correct? Superuser?